# Using URL parameters with mySQL and JSP ERROR

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

The code connects to mySQL database and makes a table which populates it with data. Each row has a buy button that is specific for that row. So the specific item code is sent to jsporder.jsp page.

```
<sql:query var="result">
select * from inventory;
</sql:query>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>Code</th>
<th>Author</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Other field(Probs price)</th>
<th>Item Stock</th>
<th>Order Stock</th>
<th>Buy option </th>
</tr>

<c:forEach var = "row" items = "${result.rows}">
<tr>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item_code}"/></td>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item_author}"/></td>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item_description}"/></td>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item_price}"/></td>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item__stock_count}"/></td>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item_order_count}"/></td>
<td><a href="jsporder.jsp?item_code=${row.item_code}">Buy!</a></td>
<td><a
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</div>
```

Now my Jsp order page I want data to change in the database.

Firstly use:

```
String itemCode = request.getParameter("item_code");
```

I think it gets the item_code from previous page?

Now I have mySQL queries that I need to change:

```
<sql:update var="count">
      <%-- update inventory - take one item from stock --%>
      update inventory set item__stock_count = item__stock_count - 1
        where item_code="${itemCode}"; //This is set to the itemCode variable
    </sql:update>
```

item_code does not match with itemCode. It does not seem to pick itemCode as anything so it does not change values in database/add any entries in database.

itemCode variable seems non existent to jsp/mysql.

New web developer. Thanks (Extra)

```
        <sql:update var="count">
      <%-- add new customer_order --%>
      insert into customer_order values
        ( '${itemCode}' "2015-02-24 11:42:30", 1, 
          "2015-02-25 11:42:30", 5789 );
    </sql:update>
```

What is displayed on the page:

```
insert into customer_order values ( '' "2015-02-24 11:42:30", 1, "2015-02-25 11:42:30", 5789 ); : Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"
```

Comment: `This code does not seem to work` .What exactly you are getting .Explain properly?

Comment: @singhakash Sorry, edited it.

Comment: @singhakash 100% do, checked database multiple times. Could be the error be that it's picking up the item_code in a string (because it has the quotation marks) For example if I clicked buy on the item_code: A001-1111 will SQL/JSP pick it up as "A001-1111" so it won't match values on databse?

Comment: yes you have to `'${itemCode}'` put it in a single quotes

Comment: @singhakash Still have errors, added some more code in edit

Comment: where are the column name for insert query and this is not good way to pass parameter use `<sql:param>`  check the [tutorial](http://javaknowledge.info/jstl-1-1-simple-insert-update-delete-example/)

Comment: What do you see when you do "View Source..." on the page with Buy! links? Are the item codes in the `<a href="jsporder.jsp?item_code=something">` legitimate values?

Comment: @singhakash I have to use this way( I know it's bad). But I don't understand why this is so difficult. I have my parameter("item_code") from the Books.jsp page. How come I can't just transfer that specific item code into mySQL databases?

Comment: Ok,but where is the column name in insert query?

Comment: @OllieJones Yeah, it shows: <a href="jsporder.jsp?item_code=AA01-001">Buy!</a>

Comment: @singhakash Customer_order. On my sql script I have my text to import inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your buy link to

```
<a href="jsporder.jsp?itemCode=${row.item_code}">Buy!</a>
```

and remove the following from *jsporder.jsp* as it's not required then.

```
String itemCode = request.getParameter("item_code");
```

Also, you probably need a comma in your *update* query here.

```
  insert into customer_order values
    ( '${param.itemCode}', "2015-02-24 11:42:30", 1, 
                         ^
      "2015-02-25 11:42:30", 5789 );
```

Verify that your `customer_order` table has five columns and are of matching data types.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The solution still does not work which is very annoying as I've been trying to fix this for 2 hours, instead of printing the item code it just shows ",". I have checked the mysql script and everything matches

Comment: Use `${param.itemCode}` to reference the value. If the query still fails, post the table structure: column names and types.

Comment: That has literally done it. At last. Thanks very much.